# How to call a child LWC method from a parent Aura cmp?

Tags: lightning-web-components, aura

I have an aura cmp(parent) that acts as a container for 2 LWC's(children). I am trying to call the `handleAddToDashboard()` method in the `stockTracker_Dashboard` LWC from the `StockTrackerContainer` aura cmp. I tried getting the child LWC using the `aura:id`, but I am getting an error. The error says "no object available" and I don't see anything helpful in the stack trace.

**How can I call the LWC(child) js method imperatively from the Aura(parent) js method?** Code below:

**`stockTracker_Dashboard` LWC (child)**:

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';

export default class StockTracker_Dashboard extends LightningElement {
    @api testValues; //@api allows parent aura cmp to access and set testValue


    @api handleAddToDashboard(stockSymbol) {
        this.testValues += stockSymbol; 
        console.log('this.testValues: ' + this.testValues);
    }
}
```

Cmp:

```
<template>
    <div>Div in dashboard</div>
</template>
```

**`StockTrackerContainer` aura cmp (parent)**:

JS:

```
({
    getValueFromLwc : function(component, event, helper) {
        let dashboardCmp = component.find("dashboardCmp");
        console.log('dashboardCmp: ' + dashboardCmp);
        dashboardCmp.handleAddToDashboard(event.getParam('selectedSymbol')); //<-ERROR HERE
    }
})
```

CMP:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable">
  
    <aura:attribute name="selectedSymbolValue" type="String"/>
    <div>selectedSymbolValue: {!v.selectedSymbolValue}</div>

    <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
        <div style="background-color: white; height: 500px; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;" class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
          <span class="slds-align_absolute-center">Search</span>

          <c:stockTracker_Search onaddtodashboard="{!c.getValueFromLwc}"></c:stockTracker_Search> <br /> <br />
        </div>

        <div style="background-color: white; height: 500px; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px; flex: auto"  class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
          <span class="slds-align_absolute-center">Dashboard</span>


          <!--DASHBOARD LWC (LMS)-->
          <c:stockTracker_Dashboard aura:id="dashboardCmp" testValue="hello world"></c:stockTracker_Dashboard>
        </div>
      </div>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to call the method?  this sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: I'm trying to pass a stock symbol from a different LWC to the aura container(which i have working), and now down from the aura container to the Dashboard LWC.

Answer (score 0):

When working with LWCs, you should only be setting public properties via the parent.  The LWC shouldn't be modifying any of its own public properties.

See also:  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_components_data_flow

What does this actually mean?

In your case, your Aura Component should maintain the state of the of you `testValue`.  When the `testValue` changes in your aura component, the `stockTracker_Dashboard` will rerender with the new value.  In other words, don't call a method on the LWC, just change the data in your Aura Component.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know that about best practices. But in terms of fixing the error i was having i posted another answer

Answer (score 0):

After replacing `let dashboardCmp = component.find("dashboardCmp")` with `let dashboardCmp = component.find("dashboardCmp").getElement();` this code worked.